# Json deserialize object empty

Tags: json, vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have the following function to deserialize a json:

```
 Public Sub getDataTable(ByVal json As String)

    json = <json>{"TYPE_OF_HANDSET": "4","SMS": [{"DATE": "19.10.2013 13:20","FROM": "SAWA Promo","MESSAGE": "Special offer only for you! Get 300 MB internet + 200 SR Extra Bonus valid for 7 days for only 20 SR. Send 1 to 804097 via SMS. Extra bonus can be used to call and SMS all STC numbers. Happy browsing with SAWA!"},{"DATE": "19.10.2013 13:20","FROM": "SAWA Promo","MESSAGE": "Special offer only for you! Get 300 MB internet + 200 SR Extra Bonus valid for 7 days for only 20 SR. Send 1 to 804097 via SMS. Extra bonus can be used to call and SMS all STC numbers. Happy browsing with SAWA!"}],"DESC": "Samsung GT-I9100","ID_USER": "261"}</json>.Value

    Dim data As New DataBck
    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of DataBck)(json)
    handsetType = data.handset
    DESC = data.DESC
    ID_USER = data.ID_USER
    smsDT = data.sms
End Sub
```

and the following class:

```
Public Class DataBck
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name:="TYPE_OF_HANDSET")>
Public handset As Integer
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name:="DESC")>
Public DESC As String
<System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember(Name:="ID_USER")>
Public ID_USER As Integer
Public sms As DataTable
End Class
```

when i deserialize the json all the field name are filled correctly only the field name TYPE_OF_HANDSET in being filled empty, when i replace it with HANDSET it's being filled correctly although ID_USER is being filled correctly without removing the underscore...

any suggestions?

Comment: How haven't you got `Type 'System.Data.DataTable' is not supported for deserialization of an array.` exception?

Comment: Also where is the `TYPE_OF_HANDSET` field in your class definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you use 'Handset' in your sample json. It looks like the deserialization isn't looking at your Name Attributes. You'll notice that you currently get matches on the property names themselves. That's why Handset and user_id will match. If you use

```
public Type_Of_Handset as Integer
```

it will work.